# Disable Maven Settings inheritance

Tags: maven

Maven has concept of global settings and user-level settings, that compose into effective-settings for build purposes, see [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html).

The question is, how can I disable inheritance of global settings inheritance for some particular build?

Command `mvn verify -s settings.xml` overrides only user-level settings for me, global ones are still visible in `effective-settings`.

Comment: I really don't think this is possible. By modifying the global settings, it is intended that it should always be included. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to create Maven Invoker test in fully pure and isolated environment. Right now it inherits global settings and test results might be different on different machines.

Comment: settings cannot affect the build in terms of additional plugin executions, goals or dependencies versions, by design, they can only affect properties and repositories, you have limits on what you can define in a profile defined in settings exactly for this purpose: to prevent build impacts and keep build reproducibility to a certain extend. It might not be as "pure" as you intended though. Check the ["Profiles in external files"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) section about that

Comment: @A.DiMatteo I have a Maven Invoker test that verifies if dependencies are available in various repositories, so I need to have pure "repositories" settings.

Comment: @MichalKordas you could have a pre-step (script) executing a `mvn help:active-profiles`, scan its output and crafts the target maven execution explicitly excluding (via `-P!<profile>`) active profiles defined in settings, hence isolating it by any side-effect behavior. You could then wrap everything as part of your build, letting maven invoke the script (via `exec:exec`) as such invoking maven itself _purely_, a bit cumbersome but should work

Comment: @MichalKordas If you need to check different repositories that sounds wrong..You can check if a dependency exists etc. but related to particular repository sounds wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise why it sounds wrong? E.g. I have some new and some old repositories and I want to make sure that all dependencies are in new repositories just before switching off old ones.

Comment: Are you not using a repository manager ? What are you trying to check?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using multiple instances of various repository managers (Archiva, Artifactory, Nexus), each of them containing many repositories. I'm just making sure that dependencies are in proper places, not just lying anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on an maven-invoker-plugin test you can define a separate settings.xml file in the `src/it/...`.

If you need having a separate repositories or using particular dependencies you should use the [mock repository manager](http://www.mojohaus.org/mrm/) which is intended for such things.

The basic test if you integration tests is correct start with empty local repository by using `mvn clean version` which should work.

As an example you can take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin) which uses such setup.

Comment: 1) I'm using separate `settings.xml` for my Maven Invoker builds, but they replace only user-level settings. Global settings from `conf/settings.xml` are still applied. 2) I can't use mock repository, as I want to verify real repositories.

Comment: Yes the global settings.xml will be in the game...but usually you do not change the global settings only user settings.xml. Why do you need to verify real repositories? Sounds wrong to me...Checking if dependencies exist or newer versions etc. make sense but different repositories ?

Comment: 1) But I want to make my test re-runnable so I don't have control on someone's global settings, and I know people have them set up. 2) Basically I'm trying to verify that all third-party dependencies are available in our mirror of Maven Central, all dependencies related to project A are in RA repository, all snapshots for project B are in RB repository, but not in RC repository etc.

Comment: If you have a test (in particular integration tests) you usually define prerequisites so this would one and sayong nothing is allowed being in global settings. Furthermore If you build against your mirror than you know that the required artifacts are there...I've got the impressions that i don't fully understand the problem what you exacly have...

Comment: I don't want t make prerequisites for a test, everyone should be able to run it without additional setup. I don't understand your point about mirror. What's wrong with checking that mirror contains proper data and nothing is corrupted there?